# a) have invented or b) invented

Tags: grammar

Experts report that people who lived in the region that is Iraq now
23)___ it many years ago.

What would you say for gap?
a) has invented
b) invented

Can you also explain the reason please?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

a) **has invented** is incorrect for two reasons. First, **people** is plural, so it should be **have** rather than **has**.  Second, **has invented** is present perfect: we use present perfect to describe something that occurred at an *unspecified* time in the past, and is still in effect. Here is an example:

> I **have invented** a new kind of fastener for clothing.

This sentence does not specify when I invented it, and the invention still exists, so it is still in effect.

In the original sentence, **many years ago** specifies (very approximately) when it was invented, so it is not appropriate to use present perfect.

b) **invented** is correct because the sentence talks about something that occurred in the past *at a specified time*.

---

Note that the sentence is unusual in two other ways. You normally use the word **report** for things that are happening now, or happened recently. A better word would be **state** if it's a proven fact, or **suggest** if it is a theory. When talking about a region that has changed names, we normally put **now** before the new name, rather than after it: "the region that is **now** Iraq".